# How do you pass arguments to elasticsearch inline scripts using the nodejs driver?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

The situation I want to solve is to update documents in a titles index with titles  matching certain parameters using the nodejs driver for elasticsearch. The current query I'm using is this

```
client.updateByQuery({ 
       index: "title",
       type: "type",
       body: { 
          "query": { 
             "bool": { 
               "filter": [
                 { "term": { "tvSeriesId": 123} },
                 { "term": { "tvSeriesNumber": 456} }
               ]
             } 
          }, 
          "script": { 
             "inline": "ctx._source.someRandomField = 'abc'"
          }
       }
    }, function(err, res) { 
        if (err) { 
           reportError(err) 
        } 
        cb(err, res)
    }
)
```

I want the script to be dynamic where I can pass a value to the script to change the value of a field. For example, the value of someRandomField could be declared in a previous variable before the query call. How can i pass that variable to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the script `params` to do this:

```
client.updateByQuery({ 
       index: "title",
       type: "type",
       body: { 
          "query": { 
             "bool": { 
               "filter": [
                 { "term": { "tvSeriesId": 123} },
                 { "term": { "tvSeriesNumber": 456} }
               ]
             } 
          }, 
          "script": { 
             "inline": "ctx._source.someRandomField = newValue"
             "params": {
                "newValue": newRandomFieldValue
             }
          }
       }
    }, function(err, res) { 
        if (err) { 
           reportError(err) 
        } 
        cb(err, res)
    }
)
```

`newRandomFieldValue` would be a variable in your Node.js code that is then used as a script parameter.